# Server Tomcat v7.0 unable to start

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to update a xml.file but Tomcat keep crashing with Eclipse Kepler
I have tried on 2 differents pc with Tomcat 7  but I keep getting the same error message .
I have uninstalled and reinstalled Eclipse and Tomcat but the same.
There is the cod ein the xml file that makes the machine crashed.
I have 1 file called index.jsp and 1 other called login.jsp

I have tried to replace the  url-pattern loginpage   by /loginpage with a slash
but I got the same error.

## below the code that is working before update :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Deployment</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>demo.Hello</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/HelloTest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

## Below the code that doesnt work after update :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Deployment</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>demo.Hello</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>HelloTest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/loginpage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

=====================================================

## And then the error message in the console :

```
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\v-mcor\.m2\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\v-mcor\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Users\v-mcor\Desktop\eclipse;;.
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Deployment' did not find a matching property.
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 285 ms
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Deployment]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Deployment]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JSP file login.jsp must start with a '/
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.convertJsp(ContextConfig.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.convertJsps(ContextConfig.java:1507)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1341)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 25, 2013 8:39:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

===========================================

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JSP file login.jsp must start with a '/
```

Tag [`<jsp-file>` from oracle docs says,](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13712/web_xml.htm#i1022718)

> **The full path to a JSP file within the Web application, relative to the Web application root directory.**

[Rhand answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584183/1031945) mentioned link, from that link

> **The  must start with a forward slash (/) if the JSP is in the application's root directory.**

Just change to

```
<jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
```

One more thing, from web.xml *`working before update`* you have

```
<url-pattern>/HelloTest</url-pattern>
```

And in `web.xml` *`after update`* you have

```
<url-pattern>HelloTest</url-pattern>  //missing /  
             ↑
```

Correct it

```
<url-pattern>/HelloTest</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It looks like I don't have anymore the error message from before  but when I changed the line to <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file> ,I then got the following error message within the link "http://localhost:8080/Deployment/WEB-INF/web.xml" :

 HTTP Status 404 - 

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 type Status report

 message 

 description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Apache Tomcat/7.0.42

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest to me that you should use this:

```
<jsp-file>login.jsp</jsp-file>
```

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#JSPs

> Note: The  must start with a forward slash (/) if the JSP is in the application's root directory.